# When does the Intl locale negociation fall back to the browser's default?

Tags: javascript, localization

I'm trying to understand `Intl` [locale negociation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locale_negotiation) but I am struggling with a simple use case. My browser's (firefox) default locale is french (`fr-FR`), and I have also installed `fr`, `en-US` and `en` (prioritized in the stated order).

The following happens:

```js
>> new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", { day: "numeric", month: "short" })
"Oct 20" // OK, I have "en-US" installed

>> new Date().toLocaleDateString("en", { day: "numeric", month: "short" })
"Oct 20" // OK, I have "en" installed

>> new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-XX", { day: "numeric", month: "short" })
"Oct 20" // OK, the negociation falls back to "en" which is installed

>> new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { day: "numeric", month: "short" })
"20 Oct" // ???

>> new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-UK", { day: "numeric", month: "short" })
"20 Oct" // ???
```

Why do the last instructions output `"20 Oct"` (which is the french version of the date, so probably the browser's default)? Shouldn't the locale negociation algorithm choose `en`? The behavior is consistent with Firefox and Chrome, so I must be missing something...

Comment: It's not French, it's *British English*…!?

Comment: Well, it *is* french. But I missed the fact that it was also British english (because British english differs from US english in day/month ordering), so this answers my question, thanks.

Comment: The French formatting, at least on my system, would be "20 oct."… Try with *long* month formatting instead of short to really get a clear answer.

Comment: In my comment I was referring to the "apparent" locale, not the actual locale chosen by the browser, I understand that I would get "20 October" using the long format. But you're right, in french it's actually "20 oct.", I should have noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en-XX` doesn't exist and falls back to `en`.
`en-GB` and `en-UK` both exist and both refer to *British English*, which uses `DD MMM` format.

This has nothing to do with what you have "installed". The browser supports all those locales without them having to "be installed".

Likely what you mean by "installed" is just the list of your *preferred* languages; this is just a list of languages you prefer to see content in, which will be sent to the server so the server can decide what language to return, if several options exist. It plays no role in this date formatting.

Comment: OK, did not known that en-UK was a valid locale. Also, I think I was confused by the fact that on firefox the browser's language, which is not the same as the page langue preferences but is located nearby, has to be downloaded and installed before use.

Comment: Yeah, many different language settings which must not be confused: 1) the browser's UI's language, which may need to be installed; 2) your preferred language setting, which is just an informal list; 3) locales known to Javascript to localise dates, which you probably can't influence at all.